# Google Spreadsheet conditional email notification script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, scripting, notifications, email

I am studying Google Spreadsheet script coding but not working for me. I am trying to create a **conditional automatic email notification** script

I have a lead sheet and the first column of this is named as lead owner and I have given few names in dropdown in this column... I want that when I select a name from dropdown menu then this Google spreadsheet sends an email to that person's email id that you've assigned a new lead.

Can you please help me in this.

I have used IMPORTRANGE formula too which copy and paste that lead to a different sheet named to that particular lead owner.

I am stuck on this email notification. tried few add-ons but not successful. Please help.

Comment: share your script

Comment: Do you use an event trigger? I assume that is what is missing.